# Is gcroot necessary inside a native C++ function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

I'm new to c++/cli programming and today I came across `gcroot` in one of my project and confused with its usage.
I found `gcroot` is the wrapper of `GChandle`, who notifies garbage-collector that the managed object is being referenced so the object doesn't get removed.

So it makes sense to use `gcroot` to declare properties in native class to hold reference to managed object. But I found `gcroot` is also used everywhere in the project like below:

```
int NativeFunction()
{
    gcroot<ManagedType^> xx = gcnew ManagedType();
    return xx->FunctionCalled();
}
```

is this kind of implementation a good practice? is it necessary to use `gcroot` here?

what if I declare `xx` without `gcroot`, like:

```
ManagedType^ xx = gcnew ManagedType();
```

does it create any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple levels of wrongness here.  Starting with the dead-wrong, you are right, using `gcroot<>` is entirely unnecessary and actively harmful.  It is a wrapper for GCHandle, you'll call GCHandle::Alloc(), GCHandle::ToIntPtr(), GCHandle::FromIntPtr() and GCHandle::Free() at runtime.  For no benefit whatsoever, the GC can already find the ManagedType object reference without any help.  A primary duty of the just-in-time compiler.  Your substitute is fine.

Then there is the what-the-heck wrongness, what kind of magic is being performed by the parameterless ManagedType constructor?  You'll have to take a look, there are decent odds that the author of this code just didn't realize that the `static` keyword should have been useful.  So he could have simply written ManagedType::FunctionCalled() and avoid allocating an object completely.  Relying too much on the gcroot<> crutch would certainly have prevented him from seeing that.

Then there is the nasty problem of calling this "native code".  It is not, it has to be compiled with /clr or #pragma managed in effect.  Which produces MSIL that has to be just-in-time compiled at runtime.  Just like managed code.  But without the benefits of managed code, it is just as unverifiable as native code.  And none of the benefits of native code, you won't get the extra optimizer love.  This tends to get extra bad when the entire library is getting compiled with /clr in effect.  Unfortunately the designers did too good of a job to make that easy to notice, you'd only observe the loss of performance.

Proper way is to do this the way native code always does this.  With a function pointer.  You get the one you need with Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate().  It is harder to write correctly however, and probably not something you should consider on working code unless you need to solve a perf problem.